# apache flink not able to resolve imports

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Hi iam working on the flink introduction but iam not able to import properly

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.sink.AlertSink;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Alert;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Transaction;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.source.TransactionSource;
```

these above packages are not able to import
i have used from the following site [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/try-flink/datastream_api.html)

in this link i have imported the project via mvn command

please help me resolve this

Comment: Please tell the error message given at the import statements, wheter you can see the imported classes under _Maven Dependencies_ and if you have a `module-info.java` file in the default package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this myself, and found that in order to run the application in my IDE (IntelliJ) I had to select the option under Run / Edit Configurations to 'Include dependencies with "Provided" scope'. Once I did that, everything worked fine.

[image]

I was able to build the application from the command line (via "mvn clean package") without making any changes.

Comment: Please note, the question is tagged as Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry I missed that important detail. I can't figure out how to make it work in Eclipse either.

Comment: Thanks! Was really puzzled by this one (as an InteliJ user). 
Note that the option has moved since then: as of now, we have to click on "add option" -> "use classspath of module" -> click on the corresponding drop down -> "include dependencies with provided scope"

Answer (score 0):

Can you please verify the below artifact in your maven pom.xml?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-walkthrough-table-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have used this command to generate the project. `mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-walkthrough-datastream-java \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.11.0 \
    -DgroupId=frauddetection \
    -DartifactId=frauddetection \
    -Dversion=0.1 \
    -Dpackage=spendreport \
    -DinteractiveMode=false`

Comment: i have checked pom xml its  same

Comment: can you able to download the jar files from Maven? please check the jar files under  ```<user_home>/.m2``` location in your system.

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing artifacts from different Flink versions. In this case, mixing 1.11.0 with 1.11.1 might be okay, but in general there's no guarantee they'll be compatible.

Comment: you're right David! Just wanted to make sure that imports resolves properly.