# Apache flink Kafka Connector not found

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm fairly new to flink/Java/Scala so this might be a non-question but any help is appreciated. I haven't been able to find an example that uses the Flink Kafka connector with Flink 1.13 (and works for me).

My project is here: https://github.com/sysarcher/flink-scala-tests

I want to I'm unable to use [`FlinkKafkaConsumer` (link)](https://github.com/sysarcher/flink-scala-tests/blob/main/src/main/scala/spendreport/FraudDetectionJob.scala#L42) which I want to try out.

I'm using IntelliJ Idea. The project was generated from the [tutorial on Flink's website](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/try-flink/datastream/#how-to-follow-along)

- The First problem seemed to be the provided scope as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63667067/3760442 ... Now, DataStream API (and the example) seem to work.
- The current problem is that I'm not able to use the Kafka connector which I'm looking to try out.

The following link was used to generate the project: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/try-flink/datastream/#how-to-follow-along

**Error Encountered**

```
$ mvn clean compile
[INFO] ...
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected
[ERROR] /hide/abs/path/github/flink-stuff/frauddetection/src/main/scala/spendreport/FraudDetectionJob.scala:42: error: not found: type FlinkKafkaConsumer
[ERROR]     val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("car.create", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
[ERROR]                             ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

#### UPDATE:

One problem was the missing `import` statement:

```scala
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
```

I can build the artifacts using `mvn clean compile` but IntelliJ still complains with the following error:

```
/long/path/flink-stuff/frauddetection/src/main/scala/spendreport/FraudDetectionJob.scala:30:35
object connectors is not a member of package org.apache.flink.streaming
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with IntelliJ's indexing (or something, I'm not sure). I pressed `CTRL+SHIFT+A` and typed `Reload All Maven Projects`. Thereafter, the build was successful.

This comment helped: https://lists.apache.org/x/thread.html/rc332d1054886e35af65de4a7c38553e02a2304a2ebdab8197badd94d@%3Cuser.flink.apache.org%3E

> It seems sometime IntelliJ does not works well for index, perhaps you could choose mvn -> reimport project from the context menu, if it still not work, perhaps you might try remove the .idea and .iml file and re-open the project again.